# Creating a ScheduledExectorService from a Scala ExecutionContext

Tags: java, scala

I'm trying to decouple an API from akka. I would like to take a scala ExecutionContext's thread pool and use that to create a `java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService`

Is this possible?

From what I can tell, `ScheduledExecutorService` can only create new threads and not leverage existing threads? Is that true?

What I really want to do is something like

```scala
val ec: ExecutionContext = scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.global
val scheduler: ScheduledExecutorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(ec)
```

However I can't seem to figure out how to do this?

Comment: I don't know such option. Why do you need that?

Comment: Allocating new threads for tasks that are run periodically seems wasteful.

Comment: It is usually more common to do the opposite, create a `ScheduledExecutorService` and from that create your own `ExecutionContext`

Comment: Some more context, if it is useful with working code https://github.com/bitcoin-s/bitcoin-s/pull/2725#issue-580174458